# $\{x \in E,\forall r \geq 0, \lim_{q \to r^+,q \in \mathbb{Q}} f_q(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\} \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and for every $r \geq 0, f_r:E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. Let $G=\{x \in E,\forall r \geq 0, \lim_{q \to r^+,q \in \mathbb{Q}} f_q(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\}.$

Prove that $G \in \mathcal{F}.$

We can note that $G=\bigcap_{r \geq 0}\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}^*}\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}\bigcap_{(q_1,q_2) \in ]r,r+1/k[^2 \cap \mathbb{Q}^2}\{x \in E,|f_{q_1}(x)-f_{q_2}(x)| \leq 1/p\}.$

The problem is with the first intersection, is there a way to rewrite-make it countable?

Comment: This question was asked in mathoverflow yesterday.  I provided a hint in a comment.  The question was deleted.  Today, the question was asked again, here in math.se and also in mathoverflow.  The mathoverflow version has now been deleted again.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the hint! The old question was a particular version where we use up-crossing inequality, in the above question we don't have a measure, only a measurable space so the up-crossing doesn't work in this case.